# Extracting the end of a URL and adding it into an href

Tags: jquery

Why im doing this is to long to explain but im trying to take the last part of a URL and then add it into the start of an anchor tag e.g.

```
http://www.website.com/page/home
```

So "home" would end up below:

```
<div class="officeBtns"> 
<a class="linkbuttons locBtn" href="home#something1">Button1</a>
<a class="linkbuttons locBtn" href="home#something2">Button2</a>
<a class="linkbuttons locBtn" href="home#something3">Button3</a>
</div>
```

I dont want to replace the entire href as I still need "#something" on the end.
I also need it to ignore anything on the end of the url for example

```
http://www.website.com/page/home#blah
```

or

```
http://www.website.com/page/home?blah=blah
```

So far this is my unfinished code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url == '/' ? window.location.origin + '/?$' : url.replace(/\/$/,'')); 

    $('.officeBtns a').each(function(){
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){

INSERT URL INTO HREF BEFORE THE #

        }
    });

 });
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like a pattern problem. Try to get the least part   between # and ? or the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;

    var lastSegment = url.substr( url.lastIndexOf( '/' ) + 1);
    var questionMarkIndex = lastSegment.indexOf( '?' );
    if ( questionMarkIndex > -1 ) {
        lastSegment = lastSegment.substr( 0, questionMarkIndex );
    }

    $( '.officeBtns a' ).each( function( index, element ) {
        var href = $( element ).attr( 'href' );
        if( href.indexOf( '#' ) > -1 ) {
            $( element ).attr( 'href', lastSegment + href.substr( href.indexOf( '#' ) ) );
        } else {
            $( element ).attr( 'href', lastSegment );
        }
    });

});
```